# What is the expected frequency response of a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

Would it be possible to do a experimental setup where I create a dynamic pressure (10-500 Hz) of around 0.1-2 MPa, using a high force piezoelectric pushing on a piston on a Small volume of oil fluid. How the change in volume will affect the pressure on my fluid and how fast this will happen across a 500 hz band ?

What is my intention:

I will be changing the volume of the oil with the help of the piezo actuator, across a 500 Hz band. The unknown is the ∂P(t) that the pressure sensor will sense. The fluid will be enclosed inside a cylindrical tube (with minimum deflection), approx. 8mm x 400 mm. (displacement of piezo actuators are in the order of -100 µm).

Comment: You are not really providing enough detail to answer this question. The answer is probably yes, but then how much accuracy do you require in the pressure amplitude and how much harmonic distortion can you accept? Any approach will likely require some means of sensing the pressure and applying feedback controls.

Comment: Well, I work on electronics, (energy harvesting) . So I need to provide a pressure disturbance to my test subject, the pressure amplitude should be around 0-2 MPa and the precision is not important. I can take 3-4 harmonics. I'll be sensing the pressure with a piezoelectric pressure sensor @ 5khz.  I wanted to know if the ∂P  will follow the relation of a compressible fluid : ∂P/B=∂V/V, where B: bulk modulus of the oil. Or it will follow another behaviour. I have zero knowledge in fluid dynamics, been reading about it, but cannot find a good answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: So let me help you rephrase your question to the group. If I'm understanding you really want to know how your particular fluid will respond across your 500 Hz band. Or rather "What is the expected frequency response of a fluid?" The bulk modulus is based on a *static* measurement of change in volume over change in pressure. So if you make volume changes more rapidly does the fluid intrinsically attenuate or amplify pressure changes, and at what frequencies? I don't know the answer, but an interesting question. ...

Comment: ... I suspect the response also has to do with the size, shape of the container that encloses the fluid.

Comment: Furthermore I would expect the 'cutoff' frequency for an oil to be greatly larger than 500 Hz.

Comment: ... just a gut feel.

Comment: Yes, so I will be changing the volume of the oil with the help of the piezo actuator, across  a 500 Hz band.  The unknown is the ∂P(t) that the pressure sensor will sense. The fluid will be enclosed inside a cylindrical tube (with minimum deflection), approx. 8mm x 400 mm. (displacement of piezo actuators are in the order of -100 µm).

Comment: The trouble is you need to make sure the piezo actuator and pressure sensor  frequency response functions are both 'flat' out to at least 500 Hz. Also the 'loading' or rather reaction force of the fluid on the piezo may limit its effective bandwidth.

Comment: Pressure sensor response is flat up to 300khz (kilter) and the resonance of the piezo actuator is 30khz, so I think I'm good on that side. The loading may decrease the resonance of the actuator to 1-4kHz.

Comment: If your post would be closed, give a new try to the https://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @peterh if the OP were to rephrase the question as I suggested it would make interesting and more relevant subject matter for the Physics Stack.

Comment: @peterh if I'm not mistaken he's really interested in how the *fluid* is expected to respond - assuming the actuator and sensor aren't affected by loading.

Comment: @peterh in other words if you suddenly change volume (step change) how fast does pressure change. The state equation says instantly but there are other equations of thermodynamics that would limit the speed in changing pressure.